# When i execute unittest command "python3 -m unittest filepath/filename.py" it showing improperly configured error

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, unit-testing

When I execute the unit test command: `python3 -m unittest filepath/filename.py` it throws an improperly configured error, could anyone help with this, it would be much appreciated

**Error:**

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but 
settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Comment: if you run `python -m django unittestfilepath/filename.py` it should work because when you run `django` as a subcommand the environment variable is set

Answer (score 1):

You need to set which settings file you need to run the unit test.

on Linux

```
$ export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=your_setting
```

please read this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/unit-tests/#testing-other-python-versions-and-database-backends